# Trying to text from my iOS app fails with wrong number error

Tags: ios, sms

So I have a button in my app that people can click which is suppose to open the chat app and allow the user to send a text to the number I specify.

Here is the code:

```
    NSString *phoneNumberStuff = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel:%@",self.driverPhoneNumber];
    NSString *stringURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"sms:%@",phoneNumberStuff];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

What happens is when I click the SMS button it opens the texting app and I see in the TO: field the correct phone number to text a message to. So I type a message and hit send, but I get this response back.

"15558354439876552 Error Invalid Number. Please re-send using a valid 10 digit mobile number or valid short code. text again"

Anyone have a clue?

Comment: is this your program? obviously there might be some validation in the code to check for 10 digit number before proceeding. I dont think it is an error it is just something the developer forcing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your format for the url isn't correct.

You are using

```
sms:tel:1234567890
```

When you should use

```
sms:1234567890
```